# EWS Data Contact Property for OrganizationalIDNumber

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

Using EWS Managed API 2.2, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact, I'd like to set the OrganizationalIDNumber property to store the employee number, but I cannot locate this or a similar property.

Please provide the code highlighting the contact property to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Extended Properties(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633691(v=exchg.80).aspx)
Below is my code to create a OrganizationalIDNumber where you can store integers (IDs)

```
var organizationalIdTag = 0x3A10;
var oContact = new Contact(pExchangeService);
oContact.setExtendedProperty(organizationalIdTag, <<INSERT string OF ID HERE>>);
oContact.Save();
```

Comment: I adapted your code for C#:      `ExtendedPropertyDefinition oOrganizationalIDNumber = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "OrganizationalIDNumber", MapiPropertyType.Integer);
                        contact.SetExtendedProperty(oOrganizationalIDNumber,eid)`. The trouble still is that in Outlook under "All Contact fields", the Organizational ID Number is still empty. Where can I find the value of the extended property there?

Comment: I apologize I didnt know that was an actual property that already exists please see the updated answer

Comment: How did you figure out the OrganizationalID tag value? From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526356(v=exchg.10).aspx 
CdoPR_ORGANIZATIONAL_ID_NUMBER  &H3A10001E ?

Answer (score 1):

@rojobo: Thank you so much for pointing me into the right direction; below the code that finally worked.

```
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition orgId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A10, MapiPropertyType.String);
    oContact.SetExtendedProperty(orgId,stringValueHere);
    oContact.Save();
```